# Invalid operation: plan should not reference subplan's variable

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-quicksight

does anybody know what happened? i was using sql coding in quicksight to prepare data, but i don't know why i get this bug
my code:

```
select c.event_time from listing_events_with_counter c
```

[a screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcQlh.png)

i just want to simply extract this column, then i just get this error:
Error details
region:
eu-west-1
timestamp:
1673292426845
requestId:
971acbe3-c266-4bae-8c09-ec54258c99ca
sourceErrorCode:
500310
sourceErrorMessage:
Amazon Invalid operation: plan should not reference subplan's variable;
sourceErrorState:
XX000
sourceException:
java.sql.SQLException
sourceType:
REDSHIFT

Comment: Welcome! Can you please [read about why text is better than images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to add transcriptions of your images of text into actual text? See [/editing-help](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks.

Comment: Can you please fix the formatting of your post? You can see [/editing-help](/editing-help) for help on how to do so.